# WPF XAML slow start up for a small application

Tags: wpf, performance, xaml

I'm using VS2010 WPF / XMAL to create a very detailed order form. It has about 50 data items on it all data-bound in xaml. All is fine in development on my win7 PC. When I deploy the app, via one click or an MSI, the application take seconds to download but up to 5 mins to prepare before the login screen is shown on a windows 7 pc. But on my XP machine it's done in seconds, for exactly the same app!. I've trouble shot the order form by commenting out some of the xaml I found that there is breaking point to the amount of items it can show before I get a start up problem. For example I have 30 items without issue but once you add one more then they very slow startup times occur. It doesn't matter which area of the xaml I comment out as soon as it goes to one extra I get the slow start up time?

I'm only using grids, stack panels and textboxes with single items of data. No lists

Very strange as XP doesn't have this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: download .NET profiling tools and see where the time goes.

Comment: Might also share some generic code/xaml that reproduces the behavior.

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML.

Answer (score 0):

What graphics cards do you have in each machine? It may be to do with there DirectX compatibility? Changing to software rendering might give you an insight (or at least some consistency.

Try the advice from this page:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf.aspx

This is the profiling tool you should use for WPF:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

On my windows 7 pc I changed these setting in symantec antivirus; In Auto-protect I disable the Enable File System Auto-Protect option. Also in the global settings I disabled "Insight for"  and " Enable bloodhound heuristic virus detection.

After this my app loaded in a second. When I enabled the virus settings back to what it was and did a reboot my app continued load up in seconds.

I'm not sure why Symantec was inconsistent with this issue... By just adding one extra line of xaml, be it a textbox or a label I get a massive difference in behaviour. My assemblies are sign on my build server with domain certificate so I would assume they are trusted.